# Fail to boot Arch Linux after kernel upgrade

Tags: arch-linux

I upgraded my Arch Linux using `pacman -Syu`, and then `reboot`. The machine failed to boot, thus I switched to `tty` to troubleshoot. The following is my findings.

1. `systemctl --failed` shows that `systemd-modules-load.service` failed.
2. `sudo journalctl -u systemd-modules-load.service` shows that:

```
Failed to look up module alias `crypto_user`: Function not implemented
Failed to look up modules alias `sg`: Function not implemented
Failed to look up modules alias `vboxdrv`: Function not implemented
Failed to look up modules alias `vboxnetadp`: Function not implemented
Failed to look up modules alias `vboxnetflt`: Function not implemented
```

3. `uname -r` shows that `5.4.8-arch1-1`.
4. `Pacman -Q linux` shows that `linux 5.7.8.arch1-1`.
5. `ls /lib/modules` shows that `5.7.8.arch1-1`.
6. `ls /boot` shows that:

```
initramfs-linux-fallback.img  initramfs-linux.img  intel-code.img  vmlinuz-linux
```

Can you please help me to resolve (recover) the issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You kernel version does not match the version of your modules.

- Boot from a Live USB/CD
- mount your partition on `/mnt`
- mount boot on `/mnt/boot`
- `arch-chroot /mnt`
- run `pacman -Syu linux`

This should reinstall the kernel. Make sure boot is mounted correctly after you reboot.

Comment: Can I recover from my existing Arch instead?

Comment: @Patrick Since you said "failed to boot", I guess not.